# Create responsive layout with 4 square buttons

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like to create a layout like this one:

[image]

The black border indicates the width of the window (or the container).
The pink squares are simple `divs` that I will then treat as buttons. They always have all four the same size and are always square.

The maximum width of the single button must be `300px` and the minimum `50px`.
When there is enough space, all four buttons are on the same line, otherwise the last two are positioned on a new line.
The buttons are resizable. The important thing is that they are never smaller than `50px` and are always square.

How can I do? I tried using Flexbox like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVpzYe

But obviously it doesn't work. Then I don't know how to set the right height.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.firstChildren {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  minWidth: 50px;
}

.secondChildren {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstChildren">
    <div class="secondChildren" />
    <div class="secondChildren" />
  </div>
  <div class="firstChildren">
    <div class="secondChildren" />
    <div class="secondChildren" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: note! `min-width` not `minWidth`

Comment: do you must use this html structure?

Comment: @לבנימלכה Thanks for the reply. No, I can change the html structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintaining the same markup you can nested flexboxes:

- use `flex: 1 1 50%` for the `firstChildren` so that they share equal space in the row,
- set `flex: 1` on the `secondChildren` element to stretch to the available space,
- set `min-width: 50px` on the `secondChildren` for the minimum width requirement,

Now add some margin to the boxes and use `padding-top: 100%` on a *pseudo element* to make the boxes squares (*note that the 300px `max-width` restriction for the boxes is applied on the `firstChild` element adjusting for this margin*) - try changing the window size and check the below snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.firstChildren {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 640px; /* max-width = 300px + 4 x 10px margin */
}

.secondChildren {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 50px; /* minimum width */
  margin: 10px;
}

.secondChildren:after { /* create squares */
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstChildren">
    <div class="secondChildren"></div>
    <div class="secondChildren"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="firstChildren">
    <div class="secondChildren"></div>
    <div class="secondChildren"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good but buttons are always on the same line

Comment: @marielle try reducing the window width, you can see than after the items are at a minimum of 50px a new row will come

Answer (score 0):

Use [`flex: 0 1 ...`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

**Note!**

you have to close div with `</div>` not `/`

[See working code](http://jsfiddle.net/0jfoc3t7/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.firstChildren {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.secondChildren {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  height: 30vh;
  background: pink;
  margin: 2rem;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="firstChildren">
  <div class="secondChildren"></div>
    <div class="secondChildren"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="firstChildren">
    <div class="secondChildren"></div>
    <div class="secondChildren"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I want. The buttons are not square and I prefer that became smaller the space between them, for example min space 5px. It is also possible to use CSS Grid?

Comment: the space is about `margin: 2rem;`

Comment: Should be responsive, bigger is there is more space, smaller otherwise

Comment: try `margin: 2vh 2vw 2vh 2vw;` or use `media-query`:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp